# Calling Python from Ruby - PyPy compatibility

Tags: python, ruby, pypy

I'm looking to call Python code from Ruby. There are a few existing tools to do this and a few questions on this site recommending http://rubypython.rubyforge.org/, which works by embedding the Python interpreter in Ruby. I'm working on an app that uses libraries unique to Python (namely graph-tool, which I have reasons for using over, say RGL), but the final project is in Rails so having Ruby code do the controlling work would be ideal. I want it to be speedy so I'm using PyPy. Is there a way to get the PyPy interpreter embedded in Ruby code, or to make the Python interpreter in `rubypython` run PyPy?

Comment: Have you considered using a Python virtual machine built on the JVM and using JRuby? It would be trivial to share data between them if you took this approach.

Comment: Something like unholy by `why_`

Comment: @ZephyrPellerin: That doesn't really help the OP's problem. If he just wants to use any Python, he's already got that from rubypython and a standard CPython interpreter. He wants to run PyPy instead. Being able to run Jython doesn't get him any closer to that.

Comment: Saying "I want it to be speedy so I'm using PyPy" is a bit misleading. PyPy is anywhere from 0.1 to 20x the speed for given bits of Python. If there's some bottleneck code that you've actually profiled, and PyPy gives a measurable performance gain for that bottleneck, then it's a reasonable issue. At that point, you have to decide whether it's easier to rewrite things to communicate between PyPy and ruby more indirectly (e.g., via popen, or over a socket), or to find a different way to optimize that bottleneck (e.g., with Cython).

Comment: Can we challenge your givens a bit? Why not use Django instead of Rails? Or why not use Rails and a different graph library, such as [Neo4J](https://github.com/andreasronge/neo4j), or the many java libraries available if you used the JRuby platform?

Comment: Rails is set by someone else in the project and this particular graph library has algorithms that I couldn't find elsewhere (like subgraph isomorphism and motif identification), so really those two need to stay in place.

Comment: It sounds like you have three options: turn the Python code into a runnable script and popen it, turn the Python code into a service daemon and submit request to it over a socket/JSON-RPC over HTTP/whatever, or use CPython instead of PyPy. Have you done the perf tests yet to find out whether PyPy is worth it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Well, not without a lot of work.

First, RubyPython doesn't really include an embedded Python interpreter; it just wraps the interpreter at runtime. As shown in [the docs](http://rubypython.rubyforge.org/), you can run it with any Python you want, e.g.:

```
>> RubyPython.start(:python_exe => "python2.6")
```

So, what happens when you try?

```
>> RubyPython.start(:python_exe => "/usr/local/bin/pypy")
RubyPython::InvalidInterpreter: An invalid interpreter was specified.
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rubypython-0.6.3/lib/rubypython.rb:67:in `start'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rubypython-0.6.3/lib/rubypython/python.rb:10:in `synchronize'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rubypython-0.6.3/lib/rubypython/python.rb:10:in `synchronize'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rubypython-0.6.3/lib/rubypython.rb:54:in `start'
    from (irb):4
```

Unfortunately, it requires CPython 2.4-2.7. It doesn't work with CPython 3.x, PyPy, Jython, etc. Again, from the docs:

> RubyPython has been tested with the C-based Python interpreter (cpython), versions 2.4 through 2.7. Work is planned to enable Python 3 support, but has not yet been started. If you’re interested in helping us enable Python 3 support, please let us know.

Without looking at the code, I'm guessing rubypython is using rubyffi to either:
 * Wrap the CPython embedding APIs, or
 * Directly call CPython VM internals via its dll/so/dylib exports.

If it's the former, the project might be doable, but still a lot of work. PyPy doesn't support CPython's embedding APIs. If it had its own embedded APIs, you could potentially rewrite rubypython's lower level to wrap those instead, and leave the higher-level code alone. But embedding PyPy at all is still a work in progress, (See http://mail.python.org/pipermail/pypy-dev/2012-March/009661.html for the state of affairs 6 months ago.) So, you'd need to first help get PyPy embedding ready for prime time and stable, and then port the lower level of rubypython to use the different APIs.

If it's the latter, you're pretty much SOL. PyPy will never support the CPython internals, and much of what's internal for CPython is actually written in RPython or Python and then compiled for PyPy, so it's not even possible in principle. You'd have to drastically rewrite all of rubypython to find some way to make it work, instead of just porting the lower level.

One alternative is to port Ruby to RPython and use PyPy to build a Ruby interpreter and a Python interpreter that can talk to each other at a higher level; then, writing something like rubypython for PyRuby and PyPy would be trivial. But that first step is a doozy.